# Find the pdf of S.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ independent random variables with $X_j\sim N(\mu_j, \sigma_j^2)$ determinate the pdf of $S=\sum_{j=1}^n X_j$.

So i have this but i don't now how to proceed:

$$M_s(z)=E[e^{zs}]= E[e^{z\sum_{j=1}^{n} X_j}]= E \left[\prod_{j=1}^n e^{zX_j}\right]$$

Since they are independent:

$$\prod_{j=1}^n M_{X_j}(z)=\prod_{j=1}^n e^{z\mu_j+\frac{\sigma_j^2+z^2}{2}}=e^{\sum_{j=1}^n{z\mu_j+\frac{\sigma_j^2+z^2}{2}}}= e^{z\mu+\frac{1}{2}(nz^2+\sum_{j=1}^n\sigma^2_j)}$$

Then $S\sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$

Am i right?

Comment: Your mgf formula is incorrect. Use the correct formula and the answer should pop out at you.

Comment: The normal distribution is "stable."  That is, the sum of an independent collection of normally distributed random variables will be normally distributed.  So, you just need to figure out the mean and variance.

Comment: well i don't know if i'm right, but i change somethings in the problem so i got that $\mu$ is the mean and $\Sigma$ is tha variance, is it? @DougM

Comment: S is a normally distributed with $\mu_s = \sum \mu_i, \sigma_s^2 = \sum \sigma_i^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\prod_{j=1}^n M_{X_j}(z)
=\prod_{j=1}^n \exp(z\mu_j+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_j^2 \, z^2)
=\exp\left(z \, \sum_{j=1}^n \mu_j + \frac{1}{2} \, z^2 \, \sum_{j=1}^n \sigma^2_j\right)
$$

which shows that the sum has the distribution indicated by @doug-m